# Array skip for loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am facing an issue in removing a specific field from my nested arrays.
I provide you an example of my arrays:

```
 Array

       (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [no] => 1
                    [id] => 4
                    [cmp_name] => dimple
                    [group_code] => 35727748
                    [dd_name] => 
                    [email_id] => soima@xsinfosol.com
                    [mobile_no] => 9971858674
                    [additional_email] => 
                    [additional_mobile] => 
                    [email_status] => Sent
                    [sms_status] => 0
                    [read_status] => <i class='fa fa-square-o' style='font-size:30px;color:red'></i>
                    [mail_acceptence] => <i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-down' style='font-size:30px;color:red'></i>
                    [sms_acceptence] => 0
                    [action] => <a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#template_detail_1' class='btn btn-info btn-xs pop' data-placement='top' title='dimple'><i class='fa fa-list-alt'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-swl' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='4' ><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button>
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [no] => 2
                    [id] => 4
                    [cmp_name] => dimple
                    [group_code] => 35727748
                    [dd_name] => 
                    [email_id] => deepakdreams.soni@gmail.com
                    [mobile_no] => 9971858674
                    [additional_email] => 
                    [additional_mobile] => 
                    [email_status] => Sent
                    [sms_status] => 0
                    [read_status] => <i class='fa fa-check-square-o' style='font-size:30px;color:green'></i>
                    [mail_acceptence] => <i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-up' style='font-size:30px;color:green'></i>
                    [sms_acceptence] => 0
                    [action] => <a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#template_detail_1' class='btn btn-info btn-xs pop' data-placement='top' title='dimple'><i class='fa fa-list-alt'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-swl' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='4' ><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button>
                )
        }
```

I want to remove read_status from both of my nested arrays.

Comment: Great, what's your question?

Comment: Then `unset` read_status.. A simple Google Search would have fixed this

Comment: Rewrite your question to be clear and straightforward

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    unset($array[$i]['read_status']);
}
```

[For more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)